# What happens if you GRANT permissions on a view, but DENY those same permissions on its schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions, database-schema

Imagine that I have a schema `FOO`. I DENY my mother the `SELECT` permission on it, but GRANT her it on the view `FOO.BAR`. What are the consequences of this?

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server permissions work in a similar way to Windows and other permissions: a Deny always overrides a Grant. And a permission to a parent object normally includes its children, so permissions on a schema also apply to its objects.

So if you were to try select from `FOO.BAR`, the server would aggregate the grants and denies from the database, schema and object levels, leaving it with a `GRANT` and a `DENY`. Since the `DENY` always overrides the `GRANT`, permission will not be granted.

---

Note also

- A `DENY` cannot be placed on an object's owner against that object.
- `REVOKE` is different from `DENY`: it *removes* the `GRANT` or `DENY`.